# Floated Element still triggering Mouse Over, despite Clearfix

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I have a table of information that I built using an unordered list containing floated .  Each Float has been clearfixed, but the floated element is extending beyond the unordered list itself, stretching the  tag across the page and managing to trigger mouseovers far beyond the table itself.  What is the proper way to kill the floats so they essentially display:none when beyond my  element ??

[here is the html code](http://www.actionmediadesign.com/unordered_list_table.html)

```css
#sortable_list{

  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font:12px Arial Helvitica Geneva sans-serif;
}
#sortable_list li.header div{
  background-color:orange;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:default;
}
#sortable_list li div{
  display:block;
  float:left;

  border-right:1px solid #000;
  padding:3px 5px;
}
.border_bottom_1px{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
.border_bottom_2px{border-bottom:2px solid #000;}

#sortable_list li div.listitem_mesh{width:150px; border-left:1px solid #000;}
#sortable_list li div.listitem_wire_diameter_inches{width:150px;}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

a:hover li.listitem div {background-color:#e0e0e0;}
```

```html
Welded Wire Mesh
<ul id="sortable_list" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <!-- Header -->
  <li class="header clearfix">
    <div class="listitem_mesh">Mesh (Inches)</div>
    <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches">Wire Diameter (Inches)</div>
  </li>


  <!-- Items -->

  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_1px">4 x 4</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_1px">.255</div>
    </li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_1px">4 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_1px">.135</div>
    </li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">4 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.120</div>
    </li>
  </a> 

  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_1px">4 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_1px">.1055</div>
    </li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_1px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_1px">.080</div>
    </li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.250</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.1875</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.135</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.120</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.105</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.080</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1.5 x 1.5</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.105</div>
    </li> 
  </a>


  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.080</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.120</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.105</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.080</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.1875</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.135</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.120</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.105</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.092</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.080</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 1.5</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.080</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">1 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.162</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">.75 x .75</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.120</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">.75 x .75</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.105</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">.75 x .75</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.080</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">.75 x .75</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">.75 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.047</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">.625 x .625</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.041</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.047</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.041</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x 2</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.035</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2 x .5</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2.5 x 2.5</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">2.5 x 2.5</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.047</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">3 x 3</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.063</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">3 x 3</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.048</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">3 x 3</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.047</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">3 x 3</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.041</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">3 x 3</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.032</div>
    </li> 
  </a>

  <!----------------------------------  //-->



  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">4 x 4</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.032</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">4 x 4</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.028</div>
    </li> 
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="clearfix listitem">
      <div class="listitem_mesh border_bottom_2px">4 x 4</div>
      <div class="listitem_wire_diameter_inches border_bottom_2px">.025</div>
    </li> 
  </a>


</ul>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid. `ul` List element cannot contain anything other than list items `li` as child. Also, the `<ul>` itself is a block-level box, in order to shrink its width to the content, you could change the `display` to `inline-block`.

Comment: If you’d change all `<a><li>`…`</li></a>` to `<li><a>`…`</a></li>` you wouldn’t have the pointer cursor effect outside of the “table” anymore, however the `li` element would still extend to 100% width because the borders are only a visual effect from the `div`s. Speaking of tables, why don’t you simply use a `<table>` here?

Comment: This does look like a job for `<table>`, poor thing is undervalued for its proper use these days :(

Comment: [Here is a simple table if you want an easy solution](http://jsbin.com/napado/edit?html,css,output):)